# How can I figure out what functionality is being used from what header?

Tags: c, porting

I am porting a large project to Windows, and I'm stuck on unistd.h. I doubt this code is using a great deal of unistd's functionality, so I think I could be able to provide some sort of replacements for it. Meanwhile, I need to figure out what features of the header the code is using.

Is there any tool that will tell you what features of a header are being used?

Comment: Comment #include "unistd.h" lines. See everything that is not compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment #include "unistd.h" lines. See everything that is not compiled.

As requested :)